# How to pass a class type as a function parameter in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, generics, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

How can i do the following code ?

```
    func setupFetchResultController<AnyNSManagedObject>(entityToFetch: AnyNSManagedObject) {
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<entityToFetch> = entityToFetch.fetchRequest()
}
```

it produce an error with error message:

> Use of undeclared type 'entityToFetch'

also when i've tried the following code

```
    func setupFetchResultController<AnyNSManagedObject>(entityToFetch: AnyNSManagedObject) {
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<AnyNSManagedObject> = AnyNSManagedObject.fetchRequest()
}
```

it also produced an error with error message:

> Type 'AnyNSManagedObject' does not conform to protocol 'NSFetchRequestResult'

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "XXX")

Answer (score 1):

Use generics

```
func setupFetchResultController<T: NSManagedObject>(entityToFetch: T) {
    let fetchRequest = T.fetchRequest()        
}
```

or

```
func setupFetchResultController<T: NSManagedObject>(entityToFetch: T) {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = T.fetchRequest()
}
```